# How can I initialize variables with Bernoulli distribution in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, probability, bernoulli-probability

How can I initialize variables in TensorFlow?

I want to associate each weight with a Bernoulli distribution:

- with probability of p to get some value x1, and
- with probability of 1-p to get some value x2.

How should I initialize this matrix?

I wrote this code:

```
logits_y = tf.get_variable("logits", [n_input*n_hidden,2],
                           initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.))
```

The `2` in `[n_input*n_hidden, 2]` means `[p, 1-p]`.

Comment: How are you planning on using `logits_y`? In the loss function or for producing summaries?

Comment: @musically_ut I want to draw samples using logits_y, the weights now are from different Bernoulli distributions. And I want to optimize p for each weight in some way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you plan to do with your matrix, but here's how you can generate [Bernoulli distribution](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/distributions/Bernoulli) in tensorflow:

```
>>> distrib = tf.contrib.distributions.Bernoulli(probs=[0.3])
>>> sample = distrib.sample([10])
>>> sample
<tf.Tensor 'Bernoulli/sample/Reshape:0' shape=(10, 1) dtype=int32>
>>> sample.eval()
array([[0],
       [0],
       [1],
       [1],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [1],
       [0],
       [0]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The problem I have is that I want to optimize the Bernoulli distribution for each weight by drawing samples. So I must make each p as a variable  and optimize it using SGD or some similar algorithms.